# When I flush the serial buffer in Python, it stops reading

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I have programmed an Arduino to send data serially to my computer. pySerial is reading correctly from the serial, but since I always want to have the most up-to-date information, I thought I could flush the input buffer using flushInput(), but when the command is executed, I can no longer read from the serial. I tried only flushing every 51 times (because 51 is a prime number and I can easily count 51 times with a counter without having to reset it) so that the Arduino would have enough time to send the next packet of data (running at 57600 baud), but still is not working. Namely, I have used a variable to store the length of the read line using deadline(), but, as soon as I hit 51 and the input buffer gets flushed, I always get a reading of 0, which means it's not reading anything. I've read through the documentation of pySerial, but haven't found any relevant information. Does flushInput() terminate the serial connection as well? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I am running Mac OS 10.7.5 and Python 2.7.3

```
try:
    self.s = serial.Serial("/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131", 57600, timeout = 0)
    self.FlightLoopCB = self.FlightLoopCallback
    XPLMRegisterFlightLoopCallback(self, self.FlightLoopCB, self.interval, 0)
except serial.SerialException:
    self.s = None
    .
    .
    .

    self.length=0
    self.myline=self.s.readline()
    self.length=len(self.myline)
    print "Test: %i %i" % (self.length, self.j)
    if(self.length>=7):
        if(self.myline[0:2]=="R,"):
            if(self.j%51==0):
                self.s.flushInput()

            self.length=len(self.myline)
            self.myline=self.myline[2:6]
            self.myLineBytes=[0,0]

            self.myLineBytes[0]=unpack('>H', self.myline[0:2])
            self.myLineBytes[1]=unpack('>H', self.myline[2:4])
```

Comment: Could you post your code? Or at least the part of it that opens the socket and flushes the input?

Comment: PS: what platform are you running this on(windows, linux, osx, something else...)? As the pySerial code differs from one to the other this may be significant

Answer (score 9):

**Does `Serial.flushInput()` also close the stream?**

So I do dug into the code for pySerial(it's available, [you can pull it over SVN,](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=46487) I suggest you do if you have further trouble you're trying to figure out).

Since you're on OSX, python reports `os.name` as "posix" and so `serial.Serial` in fact resolves to `serial.serialposix.Serial`. The definition of `flushInput()` for that is:

```
def flushInput(self):
    """Clear input buffer, discarding all that is in the buffer."""
    if not self._isOpen: raise portNotOpenError
    termios.tcflush(self.fd, TERMIOS.TCIFLUSH)
```

(If you want to see it, it's [here](http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py?revision=455&view=markup) on line 500)

So essentially it's just a wrapper around `termios.tcflush()`. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#termios.tcflush) for that have this to say:

> termios.tcflush(fd, queue)
>
> Discard queued data on file descriptor fd. The queue selector specifies which queue: TCIFLUSH for the input queue, TCOFLUSH for the output queue, or TCIOFLUSH for both queues.

According to the docs then, it does *not* close the underlying stream, only discards data. That is probably the behaviour you were expecting in the first place.

This leads me to say that there's probably something else that's wrong with your code. There's not enough posted code to be able to deduce what, exactly the problem is.

This is just a guess, but maybe the code that increments `self.j` is inside a block which is not getting called after it hits 51 so you're always flushing? If you could post a complete code example which produces the problem(maybe some reduced set of your code which just exercises this problem that you're seeing) then I could probably help.

**PS -- A Note on premature optimisations:**

Unless whatever is producing data on the other end of the serial interface is producing data at a much higher speed than you're consuming then there's probably no need to flush in the first place because no significant amount of data will ever build up in the buffer. Somehow I doubt that a serial interface running at 57600 baud will ever be able to do that. You should check and make sure that the flushing is actually needed in the first place before doing it.

Don't do it just because you think it may be needed or "just to make sure". Check that it's actually solving a problem before doing it, otherwise this is a premature optimisation and it just increases code complexity and brittleness for no reason.